# Rails find and calculate using has_many through releationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following models:

Product:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_recommendations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recommendations, :through => :product_recommendations  
end
```

ProductRecommendation:

```
class ProductRecommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recommendation
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Recommendation:

```
class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_recommendations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :product_recommendations

  has_many :recommendation_ratings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ratings, :through => :recommendation_ratings
end
```

Rating:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recommendation_ratings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recommendations, :through => :recommendation_ratings
end
```

RecommendationRating:

```
class RecommendationRating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recommendation
  belongs_to :rating  
end
```

How would I be able to calculate the average rating for a given recommendation? My ratings table contains just 4 records, (Ratings 1-4), and I have an action in my recommendation controller which updates the RecommendationsRatings join table to associate a rating with a recommendation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_recommendations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recommendations, :through => :product_recommendations
  has_many :ratings, :through => :recommendations
end
```

and then

```
p = Product.find 1
p.ratings.average(:rating)
```

this is assuming the Ratings model has an int / float called rating which stores the rating